# how to get drop down list by type respective alphabet in ComboBoxViewerCellEditor

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

In `ComboBoxViewerCellEditor` I want to write something and as a result I will get the matching dropdown value.

Can you suggest how to get this? Please find the code below:

```
public TCOperationColumnEditable(TableViewer viewer) {
    super(viewer);
    try
    {
        this.viewer = viewer;
        //this.editor = new TextCellEditor(this.viewer.getTable());

        OperationGSON[] allOperations = OperationAPIHandler.getInstance().getAllOperations();

        ArrayList<String> opnName = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(OperationGSON opn : allOperations)
        {
            opnName.add(opn.opnName);
        }
        this.editor = new ComboBoxViewerCellEditor(this.viewer.getTable(), SWT.FULL_SELECTION );

    this.editor.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());
    this.editor.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvide());
    this.editor.setInput(opnName);
    String[] stockArr = new String[opnName.size()];
    stockArr = opnName.toArray(stockArr);
    new AutoCompleteField(this.viewer.getControl(), new CComboContentAdapter(), stockArr); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("[" + getClass().getName() + " : TCOperationColumnEditable()] - Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpWcK.png)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are asking. Is this code part of an `EditingSupport` class?

Comment: yes this is part of editing support. what i want is an auto complete drop down.http://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449

Comment: please see the attached image also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass TextCellEditor. 
For a content proposal, use field assist API of JFace 
(org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist). Content assist is enabled 
when the cell editor is activated for the first time:

```
if (contentProposalAdapter == null) {
    .... 
    // enable content assist on the cell editor's text widget 
    contentProposalAdapter = new ContentProposalAdapter(text, new TextContentAdapter(), proposalProvider, activationKeyStroke, null); 
} else { 
    contentProposalAdapter.setEnabled(true); 
}
super.activate(); 
....
```

Make sure to also override method 
TextCellEditor#dependsOnExternalFocusListener() to return false always. 
Otherwise, you'll face some serious problems concerning focus.